# How to get a Wacom Intutos CTL-490 to work in Debian 8?

Tags: drivers, debian-jessie

I bought a new Intutos CTL-490, and am having trouble getting it to work on Debian 8. Basically, it shows up when I run `lsusb`, but nothing else detects it -- `xsetwacom --list devices` shows nothing, `/dev/input/wacom` doesn't exist.

I suspect this is due to old drivers in Debian 8. [This page](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Device_IDs) says the tablet works with kernel version 4.4, input-wacom version 2.6.30, and libwacom version 0.16. As far as I can tell, Debian 8 comes with kernel version 3.16.0, xserver-xorg-input-wacom version 0.26.0, and libwacom2/libwacom-common version 0.8. I'm not totally sure how these reconcile, but it doesn't really look like these versions will work.

So, what would you suggest I do?

Comment: Upgrade jessie(8) to stretch(9), it's almost in final phase. It will be called stable in 2 months: https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2017/01/msg00004.html
It has xserver-xorg-input-wacom=0.33.0-1+b1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know version of input-wacom Debian 8 ships with, but if you are running kernel 3.16, you may need to update your input-wacom kernel driver. Instructions at: http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom

```
modinfo wacom | grep version
```

may give more information.

Comment: weird, bash doesn't recognize `modinfo` as a command, though there's a manpage. Also, `checkinstall` instead of `make install` wouldn't hurt anything, right?